# Unix comand to convert Tab separated file to pipe separated file

Tags: perl, shell, unix, awk, sed

My source csv  file is Tab separated I want to convert it into pipe (|) delimited file.
Here is some sample Records.

```
Loan_Name   Current_Data_Status Mortgage_Loan_Seller

Market Basket   RECM-PS Transfer    Underwriters
```

I tried below `sed` command.

```
sed -i 's/\t/|/g' Test.csv
```

It is converting tab to `|` but it is adding extra `|` at the end of every line. Below is the output that I am getting.

```
Loan_Name|Current_Data_Status|Mortgage_Loan_Seller| |
Market Basket|RECM-PS Transfer|Underwriters| |
```

Desired outpout should be.

```
Loan_Name|Current_Data_Status|Mortgage_Loan_Seller
Market Basket|RECM-PS Transfer|Underwriters
```

Please advise any alternate way to achieve this.

Comment: Seems to be you have two `\t (tab)` at the end.

Comment: Try this : `sed 's/\t\+/|/g' file.csv`

Comment: I tried  still i am getting one extra | at the end.

Loan_Name|Current_Data_Status|Mortgage_Loan_Seller|
Market Basket|RECM-PS Transfer|Underwriters|

Comment: Updated. Now try this : `sed -e 's/\t\+$//g' -e 's/\t\+/|/g' file.csv`

Comment: `CSV` = `Comma-Separated Values`. If your file is tab-separated then it's obviously not comma-separated so don't refer to it as CSV as that's misleading. Some people would refer to it as TSV. Very important question: can your last field ever be empty? e.g. can `foo<tab>bar<tab><tab>` ever appear in your input file? If so, add that example to your sample input/output as it will break many possible answers.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have two tabs at the end. Also, FYI, `tr` is elegant for this kind of task.

```
cat Test.csv | sed -E 's/\t+$//g' | tr '\t' '|'
```

This command first strips any trailing tabs. Note the -E is for Ubuntu type unix, it might be -r on a bsd/MacOS.

Comment: Seems slightly easier (not all sed recognize \t as a tab) to do: ` < Test.csv tr \\t \| | sed 's/|*$//'`

Comment: UUOC - sed is perfectly capable of opening files.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach: remove all trailing white space (tabs included) then run simple regex.

There are two options, depending on what output is desired when there are empty fields.

1. Replace **each tab with a pipe**. In this case, if there is an empty field we will have two pipes next to each other. This way we keep the field, even if it is empty.

   ```
   perl -lne 's/\s*$//; s/\t/|/g; print' Test.csv
   ```
2. Replace **all consecutive tabs with one pipe**. In this case, if there are empty fields they will be gone completely. This way we remove empty fields altogether. There will only be single pipes.

   ```
   perl -lne 's/\s*$//; s/\t+/|/g; print' Test.csv
   ```

The difference is between `\t` and `\t+` -- the `\t` matches a tab, the `+` after it means any number of them (at least one).

- `\t` matches precisely *one tab* (and replaces it with a pipe).  So if there are two tabs next to each other each gets replaced with a pipe.
- `\t+` matches either one tab, or two, or three (consecutive ones) ... and replaces all of them with *one pipe*.

---

Another way: Use Perl's `split` to get rid of the trailing stuff

```
perl -lne 'print join "|", grep { not /^\s*$/ } split /(\t\s*)+/' Test.csv
```

The `split` discards any trailing empty fields, so we split first. Since in this data trailing fields may also have spaces we need `\t\s*`, and as this may result in extra fields with spaces we filter, too.  Then `join` gets a clean list to put together, with a pipe as requested.  To overwrite the original file add `-i`.

Comment: @Zdim I tried above command,now I am not getting extra Pipe (|) at the end,but space also got replaced with pipe (|) I want to replace tab with pipe...:(

Comment: @Ashu  Huh, sorry, I used space for my testing!  `\s` should be `\t`.  Updating.

Comment: Now I am not getting extra Pipe (|) at the end it's not working...:(
Market Basket|RECM-PS Transfer|Underwriters|

Comment: @Ashu  I don't understand ... you are "_not getting extra pipe_" -- you mean,you are getting an extra one?  That means that you have yet some extra spaces in those last fields. Updated the answer for that, please try.   Also added another version.

Comment: @zdim, first command is adding spaces between delimiters. `abcde| |fghijk| |yz|`. But, your second command is printing as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Raju  Thank you, corrected.  That approach ended up too complicated, I switched them around.

Comment: @Ashu  The data turned out to be tricky, which was hard to see.  Now you have working solution(s).  (Passes tests for me, with any trailing tabs/spaces.)

Comment: I see that, first answer still resulting an ending delimiter, but second answer put the way OP has asked.

Comment: @Raju I think that it depends on what exactly you have in your test files. I've tried with various files, including a file written from a spreadsheet, where I entered extra fields containing spaces. Both solutions clean up everything unwanted.

Comment: @zdim Thanks but  perl script is not working in the case when  file having 2 or more consecutive Tabs in middle of empty  field, it consider all empty field  as 1 tab and replace with |, i want one tab should be replace with one pipe.
giving one scenario 

source file here field Current_Data_Status  is null field

Loan_Name Current_Data_Status Mortgage_Loan_Seller
Market Basket  Underwriters 

output :
Loan_Name|Current_Data_Status|Mortgage_Loan_Seller
Market Basket|Underwriters 

Desired output shuld be :
Market Basket||Underwriters

Comment: @Ashu  OK, I thought about that -- it is a matter of choice.  I **updated the answer** for this.  You can choose from these two options:  (1) If you want to keep the field, even if it is empty, so you would end up with `||` (two tabs). This is when you use `\t` above.  (2) If you want to remove the empty field completely, so not to have two pipes -- then you use `\t+`. The plus `+` after `\t` means to remove all tabs. Please let me know how it works.  These are details which can be set the way you want them.

Comment: @zdim..Thanks..1.Replace each tab with a pipe..solution work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same with `perl`

```
perl -p -e 's/\t+/|/g' <Test.csv >Test.txt
```

if you want to delete the last delimiter

```
perl -p -e 's/\t+/|/g' <Test.csv | sed -e 's/|$//' >Test.txt
```

Comment: I tried perl comand but still i am getting one extra | at the end. Loan_Name|Current_Data_Status|Mortgage_Loan_Seller| Market Basket|RECM-PS Transfer|Underwriters|

Comment: @Ashu, looks like you have two tab spaces at the end. use `perl -p -e 's/\t+/|/g;'s/\t\n//g' <Test.csv >Test.txt`

Comment: @Ashu, updated my answer, to delete last delimiter as well.

Comment: tried with updated perl command but still I am getting one pipe (|) at the end of every line.

Market Basket|RECM-PS Transfer|Underwriters|

Comment: @Ashu, there are two commands in the answer. Did you try with second one ?

Comment: yup I tried  with second one also but not getting desired output

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed :

```
sed ':a;s/[\t ]*$//;Ta;s/\t/|/g' Test.csv
```

It removes trailing tabs/spaces before replacing `\t` with `|`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\>\t\</|/g' file
```

This converts tabs between words to pipes. However it will not convert adjacent tabs i.e. empty fields.

```
sed 's/\>\t\</|/g;s/\t//g' file
```

Will remove leftover tabs.

```
sed 'y/\t/|/;s/\(\s*|\s*\)\+$/' file
```

Will translate tabs to pipes and remove one or more pipes (separated by optional white space) from the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/e   Current_Data_Status M/,"e|Current_Data_Status|M")}{sub(/t   RECM-PS Transfer    U/,"t|RECM-PS Transfer|U")}NF{print}' file

Loan_Name|Current_Data_Status|Mortgage_Loan_Seller
Market Basket|RECM-PS Transfer|Underwriters
```